# PHP - Insert a specific class in menu items based on id_product

Tags: php, css, class

I'm a PHP newbie and know very little about it but i need to insert a specific class for each menu item.
My idea is to reuse the 'id_product' as a class but it's not working so far!
Here's a part of the code:

```
    //Show the content of each menu
$SecondMenu      = $PDO->queryFetchAllAssoc("SELECT * FROM product WHERE sub_category_id='".$titleSecondMenu['id_sub_category']."' ORDER BY `id_product`");
//echo "SELECT * FROM product WHERE sub_category_id=".$rowTitleSecondMenu['id_sub_category']." ORDER BY sub_category_id, id_product";
if($subCatId!=$titleSecondMenu['id_sub_category'])
{
    $style = ' style="display:none;"';
}
else
{
    $style = '';
}

echo '<div id="div'.$titleSecondMenu['id_sub_category'].'"'.$style.'>'."\r";
foreach($SecondMenu as $rowSecondMenu)
{
    //echo $prodId.' '.$rowSecondMenu['id_product'].' <br />';
    //echo $subCatId.' '.$rowSecondMenu['sub_category_id'].' <br />';


    if($prodId==$rowSecondMenu['id_product'] && $subCatId==$rowSecondMenu['sub_category_id'])
    {
        $class = 'Selected';
        $color = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $class = 'Unselected';
        $color = 'color:#5c5c5c;';
    }
    //echo 'c='.$catId.'&amp;sc='.$rowSecondMenu['sub_category_id'].'&amp;p='.$rowSecondMenu['id_product'];
    switch ('c='.$catId.'&sc='.$rowSecondMenu['sub_category_id'].'&p='.$rowSecondMenu['id_product']) {

        case "c=1&sc=1&p=1":
            $url_fr = "/engraisprintemps/bio-arbres";
            $url_en = "/springfertilizers/bio-trees";
            break;

        case "c=1&sc=1&p=2":
            $url_fr = "/engraisprintemps/bio-cedres";
            $url_en = "/springfertilizers/bio-cedars";
            break;
```

Comment: I don't see where you're introducing a ID as a class. If you're creating a unique class why not make it an ID?

Comment: Thanks for the reply
As i said, i'm a newbie. Here's what i tried without success:
 
$class = 'Selected id_product';

Comment: Your code does not show us where your `$class` variable is being used. Right now you're just setting the value of `$class` in the code you have provided.